# Why does UIColor.red work but using the initializer of the UIColor does not?

Tags: ios, uikit, uicolor

I am setting a label colour in a view controller class. When I use the following code, it works.

```
self.labelTest.textColor = UIColor.red
```

[image]

However, if I use the initializer of UIColor, like the following, the label becomes "invisible".

```
self.labelTest.textColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
```

[image: n]

Can someone tell me why this is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have set alpha to **0**

self.labelTest.textColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: **0**)

set alpha to 1 in order to make it visible

```
self.labelTest.textColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

[From documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init)

> **alpha**
>
> The opacity value of the color object, specified as a value from
>   0.0 to 1.0. Alpha values below 0.0 are interpreted as 0.0, and values above 1.0 are interpreted as 1.0.